# OpenSilver with Service References

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, opensilver

Im trying to migrate a Silverlight application to OpenSilver.
The application uses WCF service references that are included in the project.

I followed the OpenSilver example on migrating from Silverlight to OpenSilver
https://doc.opensilver.net/documentation/migrate-from-silverlight/example.html

After wrapping the application with the OpenSilver files I get an error that my services namespace could not be found, then when trying to add that missing service reference to the project I get "The target framework 'netcoreapp2.0' is out of support"

Is there a step I am missing in setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

**If you get the error because you copy-pasted the server references as well**

If you double click that error it should bring you to the `Reference.svcmap` file of your WCF service reference. Find  the `Reference.cs` file in Solution Explorer next to `Reference.svcmap`.

Open it and you will see the same error multiple times in the code:

> "The type name 'IHttpCookieContainerManager' could not be found in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel.Channels'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly."

Solution: add the following nuget package: [System.ServiceModel.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Http/)

If you try to add a new service reference then follow this workaround: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/4766#issuecomment-1007859628

I hope that helps.